# Class iteration over internal numpy array ? Assignment?

Tags: python, numpy, class, iterator, assign

How do you make class to iterate by its internal numpy array :
Just idea which does not work :

```
class ABC:

  def __init__(self):
     self.ary = np.zeros(50)

  def __iter__(self): return np.nditer(self.ary)
  def next(self): ...??..
```

Also how to make assignment work too :

```
abc = ABC()
abc[5] = 12
abc[7:9] 0
```

Comment: you don't need to define `next`. Your class should work, so if it isn't working, you need to be *specific about what doesn't work*. "It doesn't work" isn't an adequate problem description. To make a class *iterable* you need to define `__iter__`. You only define `__next__` (note, it is `__next__` not `next` in Python 3) only if you want your class to be an *iterator*, in which case, `__iter__` **must** return `self`. You don't want to define an iterator, I think, but an iterable. Which you have. As to item-based assignment,  please, also, avoid asking multiple questions.

Comment: Don't use `nditer`.  It's too difficult to use right, and doesn't offer any speed benefits.

Comment: What do you hope to do with thus class?  Have you considered sublassing `list`?

Comment: What is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation,

> **iterator.__next__()**:
>
> Return the next item from the container. If there are no further items, raise the StopIteration exception. This method corresponds to the tp_iternext slot of the type structure for Python objects in the Python/C API.

For `setting` and `getting` values for container class, you need to implement `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.

For your sample code

```py
class ABC():
  def __init__(self):
     self.ary = np.zeros(50)
     self.index = self.ary.shape[0]

  def __iter__(self): 
     return np.nditer(self.ary)

  def next(self):
      if self.index == 0:
          raise StopIteration
      self.index = self.index - 1
      return self.data[self.index]

  def _check_indx(self, idx):
      if abs(idx) >= self.ary.shape[0]:
          raise IndexError(f"Invalid Index {idx} for array with shape {self.ary.shape}")

  def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
      self._check_indx(idx)
      self.ary[idx] = value

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
      self._check_indx(idx)
      return self.ary[idx]
```

Comment: why does it return arrays !!  [i for i in t]
Out[15]: 
[array(277, dtype=uint16),
 array(709, dtype=uint16),
 array(776, dtype=uint16), .......

Comment: @sten This is because of `return np.diter(self.ary)` in `__iter__(self):`, If you are planning to use this for 1-d array, you can change the return statement to `return iter(self.ary)` which will give the expected behaviour. For, Multi-dimensional cases `np.diter` would be better choice